# App not launching after installing the app with electron-wix-msi installer

Tags: electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

I  have an electronJS application, which I packaged with [`electron-forge`](https://www.electronforge.io/).I then used [`electron-wix-msi`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-wix-msi) to package the app, as per [this tutorial](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/927/how-to-create-a-msi-installer-in-windows-for-an-electron-framework-application). Everything worked fine, until it came to testing the app installed with the MSI. When I searched for the app from my start menu and clicked on it or clicked on the desktop shortcut, the app did not launch. I noticed that there were two executables installed. One of them works, but the other one (which the shortcuts are linked to) doesn't.

```
app-0.0.0/
  .......
  |--Gesture Music.exe - Executable that works, but isn't used
  .......
Gesture Music.exe - Executable that doesn't work, which shortcuts are linked to
```

Is there any way to make the shortcuts (which were created during the installation) link to the working executable?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a lot of trouble when I was using `electron-wix-msi`. Eventually I used `inno setup compiler` for making the installer (`.exe`) for my electron app. If it is not compulsory for you to make `.msi`, you can check out the tutorial I made for the whole process [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJe1YPypgKY).

Comment: I had seen your tutorial before posting this question. I was having problems installing `inno setup` using npm.

Comment: As far as I know, there is an npm package by the name of `windows-inno-installer` but you don't have to go that way. Just google `inno setup compiler` and download its setup from its website and install it. The GUI makes it easier. That's the best advice I can give. I hope you find what you are looking for and complete your application :)

Comment: I fixed it by using electron-builder instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with electron-wix-msi@3.2 when I specified the 4-level version string of my app exe. Specifying a 3-level version string solved the issue for me:

```
new MSICreator({ ... 
  version: '2.2.0', // Launcher app fails for '2.2.0.41'
})
```